# Discord.py private messages

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot that sends a DM to someone with a command like:

```
!messagesteve hello world
```

and it would send a message directly to the person I want.

I've tried the following, but to no avail:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def dm(ctx):
    user=await client.get_user_info("381870129706958")
    await client.send_message(user, "test")
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _but it doesen't work_ What happens?

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though you're using the old docs of d.py (v0.16.x). The most recent version is on rewrite (v1.x).

One of the changes, [amongst others](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html), is that context is automatically implied (you don't need `pass_context=True`) and the syntax for sending messages has changed, as you'll see in the example:

```py
@client.command()
async def dm(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, message):
    try:
        await member.send(message)
    except: # this will error if the user has blocked the bot or has server dms disabled
        await ctx.send("Sorry, that user had DMs disabled!")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Successfully sent {member} a DM!")
```

The usage, assuming a prefix of `!`, the usage of the command will be:
`!dm @Skyonimous Hey there, I'm DMing you from a bot!`

`*` in the arguments "consumes rest", which means that the argument that succeeds it (`message`) will act as one whole argument, no matter the number of spaces, so you can send a whole paragraph to a user if you want!

If there's anything that you want me to clarify, I'll be more than happy to!

---

**References:**

- [Major changes 0.16.x -> 1.x](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html)
- [Recent docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#)
- [`Member.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.send)
- [`Context.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.send)